# ¿Como juntar en un constructor tres contructores con signaturas diferentes?

Tags: c++, optimización, constructor

Tengo tres constructores de una simple clase A con signaturas diferentes pero querio hacer un solo constructor que reune las tres constructores :

```
using namespace std ;
class A {
    private : int x, y;
    public :
        A();                 // constructeur I
        A(int abs);          // constructeur II
        A(int abs, int ord); // constructeur III
        A(const A &) ;       // constructeur IV
        ~A() ;              // destructeur
        void affiche();
} ;

A::A()
{
    x = 1 ;  y = 0 ;
    cout << "constructor I             : " << x << " " << y <<endl ;
}

A::A(int abs)
{
    x = abs ;  y = 0 ;
    cout << "constructor II            : " << x << " " << y <<endl ;
}

A::A(int abs, int ord)
{
    x = abs ;  y = ord ;
    cout << "constructor III           : " << x << " " << y << endl ;
}

main ()
{
    cout << "début main" << endl ;
    A a;
    A b(2);
    A c(10,20);
    A d = a ;
    A * adr = new A (3,3) ;
    fct (a, adr) ;
    A e(30,40);
    A tab[6]={4,c,0,e};
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    tab[i].affiche();
    cout << "fin main" << endl ;
}
```

He hizo

```
A::A(int abs =1 , int ord = 0)
{
    x = abs ;  y = ord ;
    cout << "constructeur III           : " << x << " " << y << endl ;
}
```

Pero no funciona. He hizo también una inicialización en la clase pero no funciona tampoco... He hizo un constructor que inicializa las variables a menos que nos lo dan las parametros que quiere :

```
A::A(int abs, int ord)
{
    x = 1;
    y = 0;
    x = abs ;  y = ord ;
    cout << "constructeur III           : " << x << " " << y << endl ;
}
```

Y me dan los errores siguientes:

```
$ g++ A_2.cpp -o A_2
A_2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
A_2.cpp:37:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
  A a;
    ^
A_2.cpp:37:4: note: candidates are:
A_2.cpp:14:1: note: A::A(int, int)
 A::A(int abs, int ord)
 ^
A_2.cpp:14:1: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
A_2.cpp:3:7: note: A::A(const A&)
 class A {
       ^
A_2.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
A_2.cpp:38:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(int)’
  A b(2);
       ^
A_2.cpp:38:7: note: candidates are:
A_2.cpp:14:1: note: A::A(int, int)
 A::A(int abs, int ord)
 ^
A_2.cpp:14:1: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
A_2.cpp:3:7: note: A::A(const A&)
 class A {
       ^
A_2.cpp:3:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const A&’
A_2.cpp:44:19: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘A’ requested
  A tab[6]={4,c,0,e};
                   ^
A_2.cpp:44:19: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘A’ requested
A_2.cpp:44:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
A_2.cpp:44:19: note: candidates are:
A_2.cpp:14:1: note: A::A(int, int)
 A::A(int abs, int ord)
 ^
A_2.cpp:14:1: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
A_2.cpp:3:7: note: A::A(const A&)
 class A {
       ^
A_2.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Cuando dices "*no funciona*" ¿a qué te refieres? ¿qué problemas encontraste?

Answer (score 3):

Para fusionar los tres constructores has de dejar una única firma:

```
class A {
    private : int x, y;
    public :
        // A();
        // A(int abs);
        // A(int abs, int ord);
        A(int abs =1 , int ord = 0);
        A(const A &);
        ~A();
        void affiche();
};
```

Y, por supuesto, una única implementación:

```
A::A(int abs, int ord)
{
    x = abs ;  y = ord ;
    cout << "constructeur III           : " << x << " " << y << endl ;
}
```

**Importante**: nota que en la implementación no se indican los valores por defecto.

Comment: Para los valores por defecto puede usarse la inicialización in-situ. También podrían delegarse constructores para hacer una sola implementación aún teniendo varias firmas.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Sí, pero la delegación de constructores no está disponible hasta C++11 y no se hace referencia a dicho estándar en la pregunta

Comment: ¿Sería posible que `A` puede ser implementado quelquier sea el numero de variables hasta dos ?

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente, cuando se pretende unir constructores es para evitar los posibles errores derivados de escribir código (a más código, más posibilidad de errores). En tu caso quieres un constructor que haga tres cosas a la vez:

- Inicializar por defecto.
- Inicializar el miembro `x`.
- Inicializar los miembros `x` e `y`.

No es posible crear un constructor que haga tres cosas diferentes.

#### Constructor generado automáticamente.

Pero sí podemos ahorrarnos crear constructores manualmente y dejar que el compilador haga el trabajo por nosotros, el constructor por defecto puede ser reducido a:

```
class A {
    //              vvv <-- Valor por defecto de x
    private : int x = 1, y = 0;
    //                     ^^^ <-- Valor por defecto de y
    public :
        A() = default; // Se usara la construccion por defecto de los miembros de A
        // ...
};
```

Observa que se les ha asignado valor a `A::x` y `A::y` en el punto de declaración, así pues no es necesario que el constructor por defecto tenga cuerpo por lo que le decimos al compilador que lo genere por nosotros.

#### Constructor delegado.

También es posible indicar a un constructor que delegue las tareas de inicialización en otro constructor, de esta manera podemos mantener el constructor que recibe dos parámetros y delegar desde el constructor que recibe un parámetro:

```
class A {
    private : int x = 1, y = 0;
    public :
        A() = default; // Se usara la construccion por defecto de los miembros de A
        A(int abs) : A(abs, 0) {} // Se delega en el siguiente constructor 
        A(int abs, int ord) : x{abs}, y{ord} {} // Solo este constructor tiene codigo
        // ...
};
```